# AndEngine GLES2 - line-through Text

Tags: java, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I'm trying to set line-through Text in AndEngine but I can't find how. Is it possible without manually calculating position and draw line by myself?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to do it "manualy" with the position of the text-position methods
- text.getposition + text.getwidth + textgethight

Comment: I already did that, and it works but I thought there is better way :)